# Why is "pip install gym" failing with "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully" errors?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I'm struggling to install gym suddenly in Google Colab.

The error looks like this:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting gym[accept-rom-license,atari]==0.21.0
  Using cached gym-0.21.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I've upgraded pip and setuptools, and installed ez_setup, but nothing worked.

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: @Gino Mempin
 yes, it is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Downgrade your `setuptools==65.5.0` and `wheel<0.40.0`

```
!pip install setuptools==65.5.0 "wheel<0.40.0"
```

**Details:**

The issue here seems to be related to `wheel` (0.40.0+) and `setuptools` (66.0.0+) that is now reporting a version string in `gym==0.21.0`'s setup file as no longer valid. The following traceback comes from building wheel for Gym as reported in [Github #3202 for gym](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3202)

```
...
wheel.vendored.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
opencv-python>=3.
```

which refers to `opencv-python>=3.` string in the [setup.py](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/v0.21.0/setup.py#L20). It would appear that newer versions of `wheel` is raising errors here.

One workaround that you can find in [Github issue #3211](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3211) is to downgrade the versions of setuptools and wheel, as in:

```
!pip install setuptools==65.5.0 "wheel<0.40.0"
```

After restarting the kernel, you should be able to run:

```
!pip install gym==0.21.0
```